# How to databind the to attribute of vue router's routerlink with Typescript using composition API in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-router4

Here is my component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  linkPath: //what should I type here?,
  label: String,
  icon: String
})
</script>

<template>
    <RouterLink :to="linkPath">
      <font-awesome-icon :icon="icon" size="2xl" /> <span class="hidden">{{ label }}</span>
    </RouterLink>
</template>
```

From the error that I'm getting when hovering over the :to attribute, I can tell that I need the RouteLocationRaw data type to be fed into the attribute but I can't figure out how to do this. Also, assuming that I managed to hook this databinding correctly, how do I pass in the data to the props? I'm assuming it won't be as simple as just typing in the destination route.
I'm quite new to Typescript and Vue js.

I tried importing the RouteLocationRaw from vue-router and set it as my linkPath prop's type but VS Code is telling me that I'm using it as a value instead of the type of the props.

Am I supposed to do router.push() on the parent component instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to update here.

First, `linkPath` can be type `String` but here you need to specify that it is a required prop (`required:true`) so that typescript knows that it is never `undefined` which is specified in the error as well.

[image]

[Optional] Second, you need to save the reference of `defineProps()` to a `const` to be able to use it in your template.

**Updated Code**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
const props = defineProps({ linkPath: { type: String, required: true } })
</script>
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is a test page</h1>
    <!-- Both of the following ways work -->
    <RouterLink :to="linkPath">Link to something</RouterLink>
    <RouterLink :to="props.linkPath">Link to something</RouterLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. Although, I actually don't have to put the defindeProps() into a const.